# Google Universal analytics cross domain tracking

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to track cross-domain calls using Universal Analytics, I've copy-pasted the code right from the google documentation and for some reason it is not decorating the external link with the expected parameter (like `_ga=1.182119591.1441315536.1362115890410`).

Following there is the exact code we tried:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var UAAccount = 'UA-0000000-0'; 
            var UATrackerName = 'pageTracker';

            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', UAAccount, 'auto', {'allowLinker': true });
            ga( UATrackerName + '.send', 'pageview');


            function decorateMe(event) {
              event = event || window.event;                            // Cross browser hoops.
              var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

              if (target && target.href) {                              // Ensure this is a link.
                ga('linker:decorate', target);
              }
            }

            // Cross browser way to listen for events.
            function addListener(element, type, callback) {
             if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback);
             else if (element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
            }


            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var linker;
                var myLink = document.getElementById('pippo');             // Add event listeners to link.
                addListener(myLink, 'mousedown', decorateMe);
                addListener(myLink, 'keydown', decorateMe);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://www.goo.gl" id="pippo" target="_self"> anchor </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to use the dynamic linker instead of decorating each link:

```
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['goo.gl']);
```

but without success: the external link will be without the `_ga` parameter.

Comment: Turned out my problem was the combination of adding the listener to `mousedown` event and `target='_blank'` on my anchor element. Using `click` event and decorating the link in the handler did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you are giving the tracker a name of 'pageTracker', but you are not using that name when calling the object methods, including create and linker methods:

```
ga('create',  'UA-XXX-Y', {name: 'pageTracker'});
ga('pageTracker.linker' ...);
ga('pageTracker.require' ...);
```

Comment: `ga('pageTracker.create',  ...);` won't work. If you want to create a named tracker, you should call `ga('pageTracker.create',  { name: 'trackerName' });`

Comment: Yes, you're right! Fixed my answer above. Sorry about the oversight.